# how to delete all the file exept 2 "with git rm"?

Tags: git

I want develop a new branch more simple with git and i want delete all the files except two.
at home i do that :

```
git rm background.lua
git rm border.lua
git rm game.lua
....
```

Is there a way more simple like a one-line command ?
or is there a way to detach file from a branch or a commit ?

thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this will do for you:

```
git rm -r * && git reset -- file1 file2 && git checkout .
```